# Difference between C/C++ data types in Windows

Tags: windows, visual-c++

In Windows systems different data types have the same size (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz(v=VS.100).aspx) I couldn't help but wonder is there a difference between double and long double or between long and int? When I ask about differences I mean difference in calculations.

Comment: No, no difference.  Note however that this depends on the particular compiler you are using, not on the operating system the compiler is running on or targeting; that is, there might be Windows-based compilers for which long and int are different sizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the C++-standard they may be different, but don't have to. The guarantee is that the `long` versions are always at least as large as their non-`long` counterparts.

In general, the sizes of data-types depend on the system on which you are running. So while there may not be a difference on your system, there may be on others. You have to be aware of that if you want to write portable code.